# Are questions about art restoration on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

From what I understand, the scope of this site is to act as a place for people who are artists/creators of art and crafts.

Are topics that relate to art restoration/preservation considered part of that scope?

I've mentioned preservation here because some of the questions tagged [preservation](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/preservation) (or that should be) are from non-artists asking about preserving or restoring works that they own.

- [Are there markers, paints, pencils, etc that are known to not change color over time?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/205/are-there-markers-paints-pencils-etc-that-are-know-to-not-change-color-over-t)
- [What needs to be done to original art before having it framed](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-needs-to-be-done-to-original-art-before-having-it-framed)

I'm not saying that I think these questions are good or bad, they are here as examples of what I'm talking about.

Comment: Restoration and preservation may overlap significantly, but there are also some aspects of preservation that aren't about restoration (and a number of questions asked already, [tag:preservation] I think) -- can you expand a little more on that overlap out relationship, or is that perhaps best left to answers?

Comment: I think that a good answer will definitely address the differences between restoration and preservation - and hopefully, if only one of the two is in scope, can help delineate where one stops and the other starts.

Comment: @Catija I'm of the opinion that both should be on-topic - but it's actually rather difficult to say where the line is, without many examples, and "line-stretchers."

Answer (score 6):

## I say yes.

Art restoration is ultimately an art/craft in itself. Through restoring a work, you add your own arts to create a new product. I see it as perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: Yeah. These should be fine. I don't see a reason why they won't be. If one does pop up we can revisit this discussion for _that_ question. Crafts do need TLC as well.

Comment: Restoration isn't about "creating a new product"... I think you're confusing it with something like "upcycling". Restoration is about **repairing** an already existing product. Should we also answer questions about "I broke my ceramic mug, what type of glue should I use to fix it?" How is this art related?

Comment: Working with pottery and ceramics would be considered a craft. If someone just asked about their own creation that broke I would hope we would answer it as well as explain what they could have done to prevent it ( assuming it was a failure of the work.) If someone asked about a mug that was purchased from a craft outlet and not a commercial common coffee mug I would hope we consider answering it. If it was a regular coffee mug would could close it as a dupe or just mark it as off topic. Give them a chance though and see.